# How to call a function on parent controller?

Tags: mithril.js

In the snippet below I'm trying to call a function on parent's controller.

What options Mithril provides?

```js
class Parent {
  view(vnode){
    return m(Child, {onaction: this.onAction});
  }
  onAction = () => { //TO BE CALLED BY CHILD
    console.log('on action'); 
  }
};   
class Child {
  view(vnode){
    return m(Button, {onclick: this.onClick})
  }
  onClick = () => { 
    // NEEDS TO CALL PARENT'S ONACTION FUNCTION FROM HERE
    console.log('click'); 
  }
};   
class Button {
  view(vnode){
    return m('button', vnode.attrs, 'button')
  }
}
m.render(document.body, m(Parent));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mithril/1.1.1/mithril.min.js"></script>
```

One solution would be to save `vnode` in child's controller and then call `this.vnode.attrs.onaction()` from `onClick` handler, but wouldn't it be an anti-pattern?

```
class Parent {
  view(vnode){
    return m(Child, {onaction: this.onAction});
  }
  onAction = () => {
    console.log('on action'); 
  }
}; 

class Child {
  view = (vnode) => { //Is it ok to bind it?
    this.vnode = vnode;
    return m(Button, {onclick: this.onClick})
  }
  onClick = () => { 
    console.log('click'); 
    this.vnode.attrs.onaction();
  }
};
```

Comment: You have to link a function with attributes you are passing into your child component. And call the function from attrs, from your child component.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
class Parent {
  view (vnode) {
    return m(Child, {onclick: this.onAction});
  }
  onAction () {
    console.log('on action'); 
  }
};   
class Child {
  view(vnode){    
    let parentOnClick = vnode.attrs.onclick
    vnode.attrs.onclick = () => {
      parentOnClick()
        this.onAction()
    }
    return m(Button, vnode.attrs)
  }
  onAction () {     
    console.log('click'); 
  }
};   
class Button {
  view(vnode){
    return m('button', vnode.attrs, 'button')
  }
}
m.render(document.body, m(Parent));
```

[Here a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rcc1d05d/)